# What would be a better way to find out the code's SD instead of calculating by each specific code?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find out the standard deviation of A, B, C and D.

I've tried using this formula:
`=STDEVIFS()`

```
1st sheet
Code   (A, B, C, A, A, C, B, B)
Number (1, 9, 8, 4, 7, 3, 0, 4)

2nd sheet
Code   (A, B, C, D)
SD     (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=STDEVIFS()` [Isn't](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188#bm19) an officical office Excel function. Try the below.

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=STDEV.S(IF($A$2:$A$9=D2,$B$2:$B$9,""))
```

Confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you use Excel 2007 then change to `=STDEV()`

Also, what exactly do you mean by:

> *"What would be a better way to find out the code's SD instead of calculating by each specific code?"*